# Cross sum of digits of a non-negative number using list comprehension

Tags: haskell, sum, list-comprehension, digits, sum-of-digits

I'm looking for a non-recursive implementation of sum of digits (a "cross sum")  of a non-negative number like this:

```
cs :: Int -> Int 
cs n = sum digits_of_n where digits_of_n = [ . | ... ]
```

A cross sum of a number (e.g. 512) is the sum of its individual digits (e.g. 5 + 1 + 2 = 8)

cs takes a non-negative number "n" as input, then should use list comprehension to split the number to its digits (e.g. 1234 -> [1,2,3,4]), which then gets summed up.

The part where list comprehension is used is the question, I don't know how to implement that.

The "usual", recursive way would be extracting the digits from a number recursively using modulo and division, and then summing them up like this:

```
cs :: Int -> Int
cs n = if n == 0 then 0 else n `mod` 10 + cs (n `div` 10)
```

I have however difficulty expressing this without recursion and with list comprehension, does anyone have ideas regarding this?

Comment: Maybe you could try something like `map (read . pure) . show` to convert the number to string and then convert the single digits back to numbers. I might prefer the recursive solution, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me remark that such digit sums are an almost completely useless thing to compute, and there are way too many questions here about them.

...anyway – your question boils down to writing a function `Int -> [Int]` that produces the list of digits of a nonnegative number. Well, that can of course be done recursively, it can be done using `show` (which is a bit of a hack, but then, *anything* that requires the *decimal digits* will be a hack), with an [`unfold`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr), or indeed with a list comprehension. In this case, you can't very well *terminate* on having consumed all digits anymore, but you can still compute the number of digits first, then determine each *i*-th digit separately:

```
decimalDigits :: Int -> [Int]
decimalDigits n = [ _ | i <- [0 .. ceiling . logBase 10 $ fromIntegral n ]
```

Then, to compute the `i`-th digit, you'll need to use `mod` and `div` much as you would in the recursive solution, just not with 10 but its `i`-th power.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible way:

```
f x = [(x `mod` (10 ^ y)) `div` (10 ^ (y-1)) | y <- [1.. ceiling $ logBase 10 $ fromIntegral x]]
```

This assumes that the number is input as an integer. It first calculates the closest integer greater than the base 10 logarithm of the input. This value provides a boundary for the next step, where we split up the number into digits using a combination of `div` and `mod`. Putting everything together, we end up with the digits from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

another indirect one

```
sumdigits = sum . map digitToInt . show
```

you need to `import Data.Char(digitToInt)`